# How to pass Serial object as a number (New library using arduino Serial)

Tags: c++, arduino, parameter-passing

I want to create a new library which controls arduino's Serial library.

Here is what I want ...

main Sketch

```
#include <newLibrary.h>

newLibrary connection(2,9600); // 2 is Serial2, 9600 is baudRate

void main()
{
   connection.start();
}
```

newLibrary.cpp

```
newLibrary::newLibrary (uint8_t port, long baudRate)
{
   __port = port;
   __baudRate = baudRate;
}

void newLibrary::start()
{
   (Serial+port).begin(); // I need to add port to Serial to make Serial2
}
```

What I want to do is,

The user will choose which Serial port(eg. Serial/Serial1/Serial2 etc...) is going to be used with ;

```
newLibrary connection(2,9600);  // 2 is Serial2, 9600 is baudRate
```

and after that the start function in newLibrary.h will start that Serial port with an algorithm like;

```
void newLibrary::start()
{
   (Serial+port).begin(); //  Which is equal to Serial.begin() or Serial1.begin() etc
}
```

I know it can be done by if statement or switch case...

But is there another way?

Such as macros....

I know that the macros can be used like ;

```
#define serialPort (Serial##1) // so the serialPort refers to Serial1
```

But this way doesnt work for me....

Comment: please explain what problem you want to solve (in English). your pseudo C++ example doesn't make too much sense to me. consider improving your C++ basics  which will most likely allow you to solve this on your own. `(Serial+port).begin(); // I need to add port to Serial to make Serial2` is nonsense

Comment: This "code" makes no sense at all.  What are your design goals in trying this?  Your intention is not clear at all.  Try reading the datasheet for the microcontroller you're targeting.

Comment: That can be accomplished with a switch: `switch(port) { case 2: Serial2.begin(); break; }`

Comment: Yeah, I know it can be solved with if statement or switch. But I want to learn the diffrent way....

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Instead of taking a uint8_t why don't you take a Stream object and then you can pass Serial2 directly like:  newLibrary connection(Serial2,9600);

Comment: @Delta_G Can you tell or show me more about how?

Comment: You're writing a library and you don't know how to set the types your methods take?  I'll make an answer out of it. :/

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't support [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). You can't build variable names at runtime.

You could store pointers to the objects in a container.

```
#include <array>

class S {
public:
    void begin() {}
} Serial, Serial1, Serial2;

int main() {
    std::array serials = {&Serial, &Serial1, &Serial2};
    std::uint8_t port = 1;
    serials[port]->begin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking a uint8_t why don't you take a Stream object and then you can pass Serial2 directly like: newLibrary connection(Serial2,9600);

```
newLibrary::newLibrary (Stream port, long baudRate)
{
   __port = port;
   __baudRate = baudRate;
}


newLibrary connection(Serial2,9600);



void newLibrary::start()
{
   _port.begin(_baudRate); //  Which is equal to Serial.begin() or Serial1.begin() etc
}
```

Of course you also need to change the line in the class definition that defines _port, but since you didn't post that bit I'll assume you know how to do that.

Moral of the story is, those serial ports are objects of type Stream, so you can pass them around just like variables as long as you use the type Stream instead of int or byte or char.